# preg_replace everything but @ sign

Tags: php, preg-replace

I've searched for an example of this, but can't seem to find it.

I'm looking to replace everything for a string but the `@texthere`

$Input = `this is @cool isn't it?`

$Output = `@cool`

I can remove the `@cool` using `preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "", $Input);` but can't figure out how to do the opposite

Comment: Match the string that want with `preg_match`, and then just assign `$output = $extracted_string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match `@\w+` and then replace the original string. Or, if you need to use `preg_replace`, you should be able to replace everything with the first capture group:

```
$output = preg_replace('/.*(@\w+).*/', '\1', $input);
```

Solution using preg_match (I assume this will perform better):

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/@\w+/', $input, $matches);
$output = $matches[0];
```

Both patterns above do not address the issue how to handle inputs which match multiple times, such as `this is @cool and @awesome, right?`

Comment: What would be the best method for handling inputs with multiple matches? I guess it would be `preg_match_all`

Comment: Just use `preg_match_all` and iterate the results, it'll give you all matching strings.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this helped me get to a working solution.

Comment: @helion3: yeah, I know about `preg_match_all`. I was simply mentioning the limitation of the two patterns. It's easy to use preg_match_all and a loop.